# Android ListView set Number of items to show

Tags: android, layout, android-listview

How can i set the number of items to show in a list without to scroll?

Example: I have a list with 10 items. 
I want that only 3 items appears and that I have to scroll to see the rest of the items.

Answer (score 2):

I think the amount of Items shown in the Listview depends on the size that is available for the list. I would try a layout that limits the size of the list. It could be possible that such a detailed layout is not possible very easily, a different screen size could show more items etc.

Comment: the problem is i have a RelativeLayout with a header, a listview and a footer. 
But the listview only fills a part of its space in the layout, and for that there is a black space between the listview and the footer. any idea?
thanks

Comment: Janusz is basically correct. There is no way in Android to say "only show 3 items", because the definition of "3 items" may vary, if the rows are of different heights.

Comment: maybe you should post some pictures and explain your problem a little more

Comment: How do I specify the number of list entries that a listview should display(with or without scrolling)?

Answer (score 0):

just do:

```
list.remove(3);
list.remove(4);
...
list.remove(9);
```

in the constructor of the listview adapter.